# How to run angular2 in visual studio 2012?

Tags: angular, visual-studio-2012, typescript-typings

I need to work with angular2 in visual studio 2012. I tried with the following url, https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1026938/AngularJS-Getting-Started-with-Visual-Studio
But it doesnot work for me (step3)

'tsd' is not recogonized command and typescript build also not available.
Can you please provide a solution.Thanks in advance!

Comment: First of all you need to install npm, and then install tsd using command npm install -g tsd // which will install tsd globally

Comment: Yeah! I tried as you said.but it does not works.I think pixelbits answer would be helpfull.Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, VS2012 is not compatible with the latest version of TypeScript.

The VS2012 TypeScript extension supports up to v1.0:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=34790

If you plan to use TypeScript in your Angular2 application, you should consider updating to the Community VS edition:

https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/community/

and then install the VS2015 TypeScript extension (TypeScript v2.1.5)

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48593

Comment: Is it possible to use javascript in angular2 application?If so ,Can you please  share some link?

Comment: You can, but I would recommend using TypeScript.  Forget about Visual Studio.  Use VS Code: https://code.visualstudio.com/ and install TypeScript via: npm install -g typescript. Make sure you install node.js first: https://nodejs.org/en/

Comment: Thanks a lot !@ pixelbits